# Pandas: Calculating the time duration for each person

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, group-by, survival-analysis

could anyone can teach me how to calculate the time duration for each person? I'm not good at describing the question because my English sucks but as the picture shows below, I want to select the latest date for the person and then subtract the oldest date to get the time duration. Thanks[image]

I wanna get the duration time.

Answer (score 0):

If need subtract maximal dates per customers use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with [`Series.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html), last if necessary convert timedeltas to days by [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['dur'] = df.groupby('customer')['date'].transform('max').sub(df['date']).dt.days
```